# (Angular 2 + Jasmin) How can I testing a method inside a component that call a service?

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

Could anyone help me how can I create a test with Jasmine to my Component below? I am using "Observable".

test.service.ts

```
export class TestService {
http: Http;
headers: Headers;
apiRoot: string = 'service/';

    constructor(http: Http) {
        this.http = http;
        this.headers = new Headers();
        this.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    }

    getVersion(): Observable<string> {
        return this.http.get('version.txt').map(data => data.text());
    }
}
```

I would like to test the method "loadVersion" that call a service. I need also to test the success and error cases.

test.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { TestService } from './test.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.scss']
})
export class TestComponent {
  service: TestService;
  version: string;
  today: number = Date.now();

  constructor(service: TestService) {
    this.service = service;

    this.loadVersion();
  }

  loadVersion() {
    this.service.getVersion()
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.version = data;
      }, error => {
        console.log('error', error);
      });
  }
}
```

Thank you!